# Kotlin - how to make a map serializable

Tags: kotlin

I am programming in android (but for this question it might not matter). i have a kotlin map defined as follows:

```
var filters: MutableMap<String, Any?>
```

i need to pass it to another screen (Activity in android) and for this i ususally make it serializable in java. but in kotlin this data structure is not serializable.  Lets see what i am trying to do:

```
var b = Bundle()
b.putSerializable("myFilter",filters) //- this gives a compile error that filters is not serializable.
```

I tried calling filters.toMap() but that does not work either.  How is this done in kotlin ? how can i send a map to another screen in android ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use HashMap in place of MutableMap.

The bundle requires a Serialiable object. MutableMap is an interface and hence is not serialiable. HashMap is a concrete class which implements serializable. You can use any concrete sub class of Map which implements serializable

Create a hashmap :

```
val filters: HashMap<String, Any?> = HashMap()
filters.put("a", 2)
```

Or

```
val filters: HashMap<String, Any?> = hashMapOf("a" to 2)
```

Put into bundle:

```
val b = Bundle()
b.putSerializable("myFilter", filters)
```

Comment: You can simply use,  val map : HashMap<String,Any?> = mutableMapOf<String,Any?>() as HashMap<String, Any?>

Comment: Don't cast your map just to a `HashMap`. Better call the constructor of the `HashMap` with your MutableMap: `HashMap(mutableMapOf(...))`. Otherwise you may get a `ClassCastException`, if the Kotlin developers decide to not use a HashMap anymore for their MutableMaps (or you decide to refactor your code to for ex. use the immutable `mapOf`).